# Where can I download offline documentation for Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there a better way to download the Dart docs for offline viewing than to use a web crawler?

I have not found anything yet! Thanks!

Comment: What kind of documentation do you mean? If this is about http://api.dartlang.org/, then it's generated from the source code and I'd advise to use an IDE that can show it to you right inside the editor :-)

Comment: If I open 'Help > API Reference...' in the DartEditor a browser-window opens which directs me to the online docs. Do you know how I might be able to generate the docs? Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu. I just discovered dartdoc. Tons of complications just for viewing offline help-documentation!

Comment: I tried to generate the documentation api.dartlang.org like so: ./dartdoc -v ../lib/  That didn't work!

Comment: Can't you just "Save page as..." in Chrome to save the API docs on your disk?

Comment: https://devdocs.io allows you to use local storage to save documentation for quite a number of languages

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf  Dart Programming Language Specification
5th edition draft
Version 2.2
July 29, 2019

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can download a zip of the API docs from https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk/archive. (The API Docs link in the Downloads column)

For old versions:

- 1.11:  http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-408.pdf
- 2.0.0: https://github.com/chalin/dart-spec-and-grammar/blob/master/doc/dartLangSpec.pdf

Comment: while you're at it, good idea to add programmer's guide as well

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to be in Internet-less places this hollydays

Comment: This documentation seems to be outdated today (last generated 2013-11-04). Is there a simple way to get the offline documentation without too much hassle?

Comment: This link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the new link for archives here at https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk/archive. There's a direct link that downloads the latest stable API docs that can be viewed with a browser.